# Users and privileges on mysql workbench doesnt display anything

Tags: mysql-workbench

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bpj98.png)

Im trying to add a new user account for a database but as you can see , users and privileges tab doesnt show anything ,thanks in advance .

Comment: Please show an example of the script you are trying to execute. Sometimes after changeing permissions, either a restart of MySQL or running the command `FLUSH privileges;` will refresh them.

Comment: im trying to create a new user in workbench

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Workbench 8.0.17 connecting to MySQL 5.7.25.  Funny thing is that other databases work fine.  One of the working ones is 5.7.15.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have permission to see anything: https://superuser.com/a/1538619/42406

Ask someone to grant you privileges:

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'host' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```